# javascript, jQuery UI: one variable into multiple "href" strings in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Beginning from the example in:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

- jQuery/jQuery UI version: same as this example
- Setting textbox (A) and button (B) above existing tabs (in the source, between `<body>` and `<div id="tabs">`)
- Pressing (B) shows google search results with the keyword in (A)

  - First tab: result within all languages page (default)
  - Second tab: result within Japanese page

From the source I have an idea to modify as follows, but don't know how to code them.

- ex. search keyword "LEMON"
- source part: `<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>`

  - `-` `#tabs-1`
  - `+` `https:// www.google.co.jp/#q=LEMON`
- source part: `<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>`

  - `-` `#tabs-2`
  - `+` `https:// www.google.co.jp/#lr=lang_ja&q=LEMON&tbs=lr:lang_1ja`

Comment: this shows you haven't read the doc correctly

Comment: I appreciate fruitful comment, solved this by another way